# Replace all links within a div to a post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several links on a page im interested in replacing all the links within a specific div to point to a main.php with the link placed as a post to the link...

Example.php:

```
 <div id='mainpg'>
    <a href='test123.html'>TEST1</a>
    <a href='test123.html'><img src=1213.jpg/></a>
 </div>
 <a href='back'>back</a>
```

I want to use javascript or jquery to get the following

Example.php(with script):

```
 <div id='mainpg'>
    <a href='main.php?href=test123.html'>TEST1</a>
    <a href='main.php?href=test123.html'><img src=1213.jpg/></a>
 </div>
 <a href='back'>back</a>
```

also not sure if would need to be worry about urlencode due to the previous already being a link.

Thanks,
JT

Comment: Can you show us what code you have tried?

Comment: You want add query string in url on clientside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#mainpg a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('href', 'main.php?href=' + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Short and sweet Thanks! worked perfectly will accept when the time will allow!

Answer (score 1):

```
links = document.getElementById("name of div").getElementsByTagName("a")

for(i=0;i<links.length;i++)
    links.href="main.php?"+links.href
```

Comment: This would work if i needed all links on page...Only a specific div

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mainpg a').each(function() {
    var newRef = 'main.php?href=' + $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', newRef);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.each($('#mainpg a'), function() {
  $(this).attr('href','main.php?href='+$(this).attr('href'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wQ83t/1/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could use $.each to iterate over the links and change the href attribute.

Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('a').each(function(index, value){
    $(this).attr('href', 'main.php?'+($this).attr('href'));
 }

 });
```

You might have to tweak it slightly, didn't test it.